# How do you programmatically switch page contexts in chrome devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

One of the dropdowns at the bottom of the chrome devtools javascript console is the page-context menu, which lets you switch into and out of browser extension context. Is there a way to do this directly from the js console?

Comment: Curious to know if you found an answer to this...

Comment: @haylem No, I never did. I was hoping to make a dev tools extension to better display chrome.storage but each loaded extension has their own version of that with (afaik) no way for a potential dev tools extension to access it.